# Excel 2016/2013 crashes running SaveAs method 2 times

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to create several new workbooks. The VBA code below runs fine with Excel 365 and 2010. BUT with Excel 2013 or 2016, it runs fine the first time (and create the files)... and on the second run, Excel crashes without any error message.

If I run it step by step, I see that it's the `SaveAs` line that causes the crash.

I tried to kill the file before saving, too. To use a timer...

I tried to repair Office, to rename a HKEY (Identities), I tried to run it on 2 different windows (7 or 10). Nothing helps :/

```
Sub ExtraireType()
Dim shVentes As Worksheet
Dim rngVentes As Range
Dim rngTypes As Range
Dim shNew As Worksheet
Dim wkbNew As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim zaza As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set shVentes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ventes")
Set rngVentes = shVentes.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rngTypes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste").Range("A2:A4")
strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

For Each zaza In rngTypes
    rngVentes.AutoFilter
    rngVentes.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=zaza.Value
    rngVentes.Copy
    Set shNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    shNew.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    shNew.Move
    Set wkbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbNew.SaveAs strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    wkbNew.Close
    Set shNew = Nothing
    Set wkbNew = Nothing
Next zaza

Set rngVentes = Nothing
Set shVentes = Nothing
Set rngTypes = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

This code runs well with Excel 2010 or 2019/365. But I have to use it with 2013 or 2016 :(

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help !

Comment: There's some external code that needs to be given the opportunity to run, between `shNew.Move` and `Set wkbNew = ActiveWorkbook`. Try adding `DoEvents` after the `shNew.Move` instruction, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, but still crashing :(

Comment: What is the value of `strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")` at the time of crash. use a `Msgbox` before that line to see the value

Comment: C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\TypeGrossiste20191111

Comment: We ran into a similar issue.  I managed to solve it, and reviewing the code above, I wonder if the issue is that Excel is getting confused over which workbook is the "activebook".  `Set wkbNew = ActiveWorkbook`.  Perhaps try `set wkbNew = shNew.Parent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem as well and have found a workaround - use **.SaveCopyAs** instead.

In the below example, **.SaveAs** crashes Excel every second time if I've left the Excel spreadsheet open and deleted the resultant file, whilst **.SaveCopyAs** saves every time irrespective. The only difference between the two is that **.SaveAs** has more options for how to save whereas **.SaveCopyAs**'s only option is the filename.

```
Private Sub SaveAsExcelFile(TempExcelFile As Workbook, _
     NewFullFileName as string, _
     Optional FileFormat As XlFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
     Optional CreateBackup As Boolean = False)
'
' created & last edited 2020-03-06 by Timothy Daniel Cox
'
' For this example it is assumed the new file name is valid and in .xlsx format
'
    Dim NewFullFileName2 as string

    NewFullFileName2 = Replace(NewFullFileName, ".xlsx", "2.xlsx")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    TempExcelFile.SaveCopyAs Filename:=NewFullFileName 'doesn't crash here on 2nd run
    TempExcelFile.SaveAs Filename:=NewFullFileName2, FileFormat:=FileFormat, _
                         CreateBackup:=False 'will crash here on 2nd run
    Application.EnableEvents = true
End Sub
```

I still think there is a bug in Excel regarding the **.SaveAs** however:

- There's a long thread at
  https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/worksheet-save-as-to-new-workbook-crashes-excel-on-second-run.40136/#post-241024
  which after meandering has an apparent resolution as linked but - having
  downloaded the file to see what changes have been made - he only
  appears to have changed the output directory and removed a
  conflicting fileformat which was set. **IMO it did not resolve the
  issue.**
- There's another similar unsolved thread at https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/58fqlg/my_vba_code_works_at_first_but_if_used_twice_in_a/ which has no useful answers.

Comment: It helps ! Still an issue with file format (xlsm =>xlsx) but it is what it is ;)Thx

Answer (score 0):

The one of the reasons that your code crash (it crushed in my case, Excel 2016), might be because you didn't add file extension at the end of:
 wkbNew.SaveAs strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
 so it might be like:
 wkbNew.SaveAs strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
Hope it helps.

Comment: So i tried 
        `shNew.Move
        'DoEvents
        Set wkbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        'Debug.Print strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
        'wkbNew.SaveAs strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd"), FileFormat:=51`

or
        `wkbNew.SaveAs strPath & "\Type" & zaza.Value & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"`

but... nothing better, it still crashes on the second run.